# How to map array of ints using Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have a class

```
Class A
{
   public virtual int[] measurements { get; set; }
   public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
   public virtual string Instrument { get; set; } 
 }
```

How do I map using Fluent Hibernate?

thanks

Comment: Were you able to figure this problem out?

Comment: No, please see my comment below

Comment: Problem solved: Sqlite stores array in a blob. So, saving and loading works by default. So, I don't have to change. Just normal mapping worked Map(x => x.measurements );

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .CustomType(typeof(SomeType)) and map it to a comma separated string.
This is not something I would recommend.

You are probably better of creating a second class to hold the ints and using a .HasMany relationship

Answer (score 0):

`mapping.HasMany(x => x.measurements).Element("Value");`

You can change Value to whatever you want your column to be named.

Comment: But, when I try to save the object I get an error Invalid Cast (check your mapping for property type mismatches); setter of Data.A
  ----> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Collection.PersistentBag' to type 'System.Int32[]'.

Comment: Ah, if you change your data type to `IList<int>` instead of `int[]`, it would fix this error. Sounds like you don't need to use this mapping method, though.

Comment: Actually, it's 3rd party dll, so I cannot change it. But, the problem is solved. I was able to map the array to Sqlite. Sqlite stores array into BLOB. And, when I reload from the Sqlite DB, the data from the BLOB column is unpacked into the array.!!

Comment: Cool, glad that worked. I'm not 100% sure if that would work for SQL Server (which I foolishly assumed you were using), but I'm interested in giving it a shot, later.